# How can I take the pixel of any widget dynamically?

Tags: flutter

I have a text inside of Sizedbox widget. I give it a specific width to sizedbox, but I cannot give a height. Whenever the text is getting bigger, the height of the sized box increases.

How can I know this height dynamically? (with mediaquery or something like that) Is there any way to store it in a variable?

I tried some approaches, but not I am able to get the result as of yet.

Lastly I used this approach

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Size _getChildSize(BuildContext context) {
    final widget = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;

    return widget != null ? widget.size : Size.zero;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _key = GlobalKey();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
            key: _key,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            // key: _key,
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Size size = _getChildSize(context);

                print(size.height);
              },
              child: Text('olcunu gotur')),
          Container(
            //height: 875.4,
            height: 10,
            width: 411.4,
            color: Colors.indigo,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the size of any widget by using `findRenderObject()` method:

```
  //declare global key
   final _key = GlobalKey();

  // pass it to the desired widget in a widget tree
   SizedBox(key: _key)

  //call _getChildSize method, this should return the size of above SizedBox. Make sure to call this method after the first frame
  final size = _getChildSize(_key.currentContext);

  Size _getChildSize(BuildContext context) {
    
      final widget = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;

      return widget != null ? widget.size : Size.zero;
 
  }
```

Comment: Sir it does not work.Only gives the size of whole screen @Ilyos

Comment: It should work, share your code here..

Comment: I updated the code Sir.Please check it

Comment: No, it's wrong you have to pass _key.currentContext not context

Comment: thank you so much sir.I missed this part